# Rails 4.2: ActiveSupport::Subscriber and Subscriber model conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `Subscriber`'s model in my project. When I've updated it from Rails 3.2.19 to 4.2.0beta4 I've got error when tried to call some method on this model:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `method_name' for ActiveSupport::Subscriber:Class
```

It seems that Rails tries to call method from `ActiveSupport::Subscriber` class, not from `ActiveRecord::Base::Subscriber`.

How to avoid this error?

Comment: You could access it using `::Subscriber`, but that shouldn't be necessary, because your model is in the root namespace and ormally Ruby doesn't look in a lower namespace unless it is given a reason to do so. It could be a problem with the surrounding code.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this method before, but still got the same error.

Comment: In that case Ruby doesn't know the class is there at all. Is your `subscriber.rb` in an unusual location or did you change the autoloading configuration?

Comment: No, `subscriber.rb` file is located in `app/models/` folder and autoloading configuration hasn't been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a problem. In `environment.rb` I had next code:

`include ActiveSupport`

When I commented out this line all the errors are gone.